# Replaying an utterance in a Twilio voice call

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-functions

I'm trying to write a simple Twilio setup that will make an outbound call, record a user's voice message and immediately replay it back to him. I have created two functions: `startcall` and `msgin`. **StartCall** calls the user and specifies **MsgIn** in the call's `url` parameter. **MsgIn** then has two main modes of operation: initially when there is no recording attached it returns a TwiML response starting the recording, and later when called as a webhook with the appropriate parameter it plays the recording back and hangs up. At least that's what it *should* do.

According to my understanding of the documentation, I have to attach a webhook to `recordingStatusCallback`, as the recording may not yet be available when `action` webhook is invoked. However, while the function console indicates that both webhooks are executed, the call log only shows one follow-up invocation of `msgin` with a null value for `event.RecordingStatus` (which corresponds to `action`), and the call indeed hangs up without playing the recording back. What am I missing here?

```
// this function's path is /msgin

exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    if (!event.RecordingStatus && !event.RecordingUrl) {
        let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
        console.log("Initial MsgIn");
        twiml.say({ voice: 'man', language: 'en-us' }, 'Leave your message');
        twiml.record({
            playBeep: false,
            transcribe: false,
            trim: "trim-silence",
            timeout: 1,
            recordingStatusCallback: "/msgin",
            recordingStatusCallbackEvent: "completed",
            action: "/msgin"
        });
        console.log("Recording started");
        callback(null, twiml);
    }
    else if (event.RecordingStatus == "completed") {
        let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
        console.log("Supposedly callback");
        twiml.say({ voice: 'man', language: 'en-us' }, 'You said');
        twiml.play(event.RecordingUrl);
        twiml.hangup();
        callback(null, twiml);
    }
    else {
        console.log("Supposedly action");
        callback(null, "");
    }
};
```

Comment: Discovered the following Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43599336/recording-multiple-user-answers-in-twilio-call. This helps to understand why my callback processing doesn't work, but I don't understand how to use it if I want to keep the delay between recording and replay as low as possible, and I don't know how long the utterance may last.

Comment: One idea is to launch another function which relies in memcached to set/get recording status (set is invoked by callback, get is invoked by action in a 50-msec step loop).

Answer (score 0):

I've followed the instructions in the accepted answer here: [Recording multiple user answers in Twilio call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43599336/recording-multiple-user-answers-in-twilio-call) to solve this problem. There is a substantial delay before the audio recording becomes available, though.

Comment: Glad you found that answer and that it helped. There is no guarantee on how long a recording will take to become available though I'm afraid. It might improve perceived performance to a caller if you give them the option to hear again afterwards and require a keypress. That would give the recording chance to complete while the user interacted with the call.

Comment: Good idea. Or just to play some pre-recorded text along the lines of "Replaying your message now". I've also noticed that call redirection make take up to 2-3 seconds; in case this is normal and not some kind of misconfiguration on my part such an approach would also take care of this delay, too.

Comment: Redirection shouldn't take that long. How is the response time on the URL the call is redirected to?